# Connection error while running ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

While trying to run ionic android i get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
       Required by:project :CordovaLib
> Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
> Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] 
  failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

I tried most of solutions you can find with searching.

Comment: "I tried most of solutions you can find with searching".. including removing and re-adding the platform?

Comment: Yes, I did that too.